# IdentityServer4 Callback Url not returned following ASP.NET Core Identity authentication

Tags: security, asp.net-core-mvc, identityserver4

I have implemented IdentityServer4 with ASP.NET Core Identity, using a custom store:

```
        services.AddScoped<IUserStoreProxy<UserKey>, LocalUserStore<UserKey>>();
        services.AddScoped<IRoleStoreProxy<UserKey>, LocalRoleStore<UserKey>>();

        //Add ASP.NET Core Identity
        services.AddIdentity<UserKey, ApplicationRole>()
            .AddUserStore<LocalUserStore<UserKey>>()
            .AddRoleStore<LocalRoleStore<ApplicationRole>>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

        services.AddMvc();

        //Add IdentityServer
        services.AddIdentityServer().AddSigningCredential(subject_distinguished_name,
                                                              StoreLocation.LocalMachine,
                                                              NameType.SubjectDistinguishedName)
                                        .AddTemporarySigningCredential()
                                        .AddResourceStore<LocalResourceStore>()
                                        .AddClientStore<LocalClientStore>()
                                        .AddAspNetIdentity<UserKey>();
```

I have validated the configuration for a HybridAndClientCredential flow. The authorize route is called with a valid authorize request, which loads the Login page on the IdentityServer. Following a successful login attempt, the redirect URL is the root of the IdentityServer, instead of the Callback Url with the authorization code.

If I enter the authorize request in the browser, the callback url will be returned with the authorization code. However, it appears that it's only returned after calling the authorize request a second time after a successful login attempt.

What am I doing wrong here? How do I get my login page to return the Callback Url immediately following a successful login attempt?

Thank you in advance,
Andrew

Comment: can you post your client configuration?

Comment: Thanks for your willingness to help JayDeeEss, it was just a case of needing a fresh pair of eyes to troubleshoot the issue. The problem was with how I was capturing and returning the returnUrl value from the query string.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with how I was capturing and returning the returnUrl value from the authorize request's query string. The issue is now resolved.